# How to auto refresh the page once on first load after switching tabs in navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

I need to auto refresh the current webpage only once when I switch from one page to another. This is to avert a jQuery class rollover bug which is applying its classes implemented in the previous page to the new page, and hence changing its formatting.

I have tried using JS based solutions for the code which are as follows but don't seem to work properly:

```
    window.onload = function() {
        if(!window.location.hash) {
            window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
            window.location.reload();
        }
    }
```

Also:

```
    (function()
    {
      if( window.localStorage )
      {
        if( !localStorage.getItem('firstLoad') )
        {
          localStorage['firstLoad'] = true;
          window.location.reload();
        }  
        else
          localStorage.removeItem('firstLoad');
      }
    })();
```

There are no error messages per se.

I am using HTML5, CSS3, Bootstrap-4, jQuery-1.4.5.

Comment: You'd probably be better off fixing the original issue rather than patching the side effect. Refreshing the page is not an ideal situation for end users.

Comment: I can't find any reason why that bug is appearing. I have tried troubleshooting it for weeks and haven't found a clue as to why the classes are rolling over.

Comment: I support @AlexanderDeSousa's suggestion. But what is your actual problem? Page not getting reloaded?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **window.onbeforeunload** to handle anything before leaving the page

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
};
```